# Текст растягивает блок, несмотря на фиксированный размер

Tags: html, css

Есть блок, который содержит в себе два других блока. Эти два блока занимают по ширине - 25 и 75%, соответственно.

Если в блоке с 75% слишком длинный текст, то он почему-то растягивается на 10-20 пикселей в ширину. В чем проблема?

```css
/*----------DEFAULT----------*/

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
  color: #333;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.6;
}

a {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: color 0.3s linear;
}

a:hover {
  color: gold;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1170px;
  min-width: 745px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}


/*----------BACKGROUND----------*/

.bg {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(#d75100, #a1005b);
  background-attachment: fixed;
}


/*----------HEADER (HAT)----------*/

.hat {
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.hat:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1170px;
  height: 2px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #833ab4, #fd1d1d, #fcb045);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.2s linear;
}

.hat:hover:after {
  opacity: 1;
}

.hat_inner {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1170px;
  min-width: 745px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.hat_inner p {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 15px;
  font-size: 36px;
}

.hat_inner #logoDiv {
  white-space: nowrap;
}


/*----------INFO MENU (HAT)----------*/

.nav {
  display: inline-block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.nav a {
  position: relative;
  bottom: -8px;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

.nav a:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  background-color: gold;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s linear;
}

.nav a:hover:after {
  opacity: 1;
}


/*----------MAIN CONTENT----------*/

.content {
  flex-grow: 1;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1170px;
  min-width: 745px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 30px;
  display: flex;
}

.lMenu {
  width: 25%;
  margin: 0 15px;
  background-color: gray;
}

.rMenu {
  width: 75%;
  margin: 0 15px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  background-color: gray;
}


/*----------ARTICLES----------*/

.article {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.article_inner {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: filter 0.3s linear;
  z-index: 1;
}

.article_inner:hover {
  filter: blur(3px);
}

.article_inner:hover~.article_shadowing {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.article_inner #p {
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 7;
}

.article_head {
  min-height: 30px;
  padding: 0px 10px;
  color: white;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #833ab4, #fd1d1d, #fcb045);
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  transition: color 0.3s linear;
}

.article_head:hover {
  color: gold;
}

.article_shadowing {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s linear;
}

.article_expandb {
  margin: auto auto;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  border: 1px solid #fff3b8;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: white;
}


/*.article {
    position: relative;
    width: 70%;
    height: 200px;
    
    margin: 30px auto;
    
    border-radius: 5px;
    
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.article_inner {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    position: relative;
    
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    
    transition: filter 0.3s linear;
    z-index: 1;
}

.article_inner:hover {
    filter: blur(3px);
}

.article_inner:hover ~ .article_shadowing {
    opacity: 0.8;
}

.article_inner #p {
    flex-grow: 1;
    
    padding: 5px 10px;
    
    overflow: hidden;
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 7;
}

.article_head {
    min-height: 30px;
    
    padding: 0px 10px;
    
    color: white;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #833ab4, #fd1d1d, #fcb045);
    
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    transition: color 0.3s linear;
}

.article_head:hover {
    color: gold;
}

.article_shadowing {
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    
    vertical-align: middle;
    
    border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    opacity: 0;
    
    transition: opacity 0.3s linear;
}

.article_expandb {
    margin: auto auto;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    
    border: 1px solid #fff3b8;
    border-radius: 5px;
    
    color: white;
}*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/mainStyle.css">
  <title>Try1</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="bg">

    <header class="hat">
      <div class="hat_inner">
        <div id="logoDiv" style="display: inline-block;">
          <a href="index.php">
            <img src="sources/logo.png" style="margin-top: 10px;">
          </a>
          <a href="index.php">
            <p style="display: inline-block;">ИСС Антивирусы-фаги</p>
          </a>
        </div>

        <nav class="nav">
          <a href="#">О Проекте</a>
          <a href="#">Контакты</a>
          <a href="#">Войти</a>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </header>

    <div class="content">
      <div class="lMenu">

      </div>
      <div class="rMenu">

        <div class="article">
          <div class="article_inner">
            <h3 class="article_head">
              "=$row[0]"
            </h3>
            <div id="p">
              "=$row[1]"
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="article_shadowing">
            <p class="article_expandb">Читать...</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!--<?php 
                include "scripts/select_content.php";
            ?>-->
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

</body>
```

Видео прикрепляю:

> https://youtu.be/Vi9TOo6Z-kE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Использование `margin: 0 15px;` в классе `rMenu` и `lMenu` оставляет вам отступы по 15px слева и справа. Как я понимаю именно в этом и проблема.

В качестве временной альтернативы могу предложить заменить `width: 75%;` на `width: calc(75% - 60px);`, что решает проблему, если я не ошибаюсь.

Было бы интересно самому узнать, как вычисление ширины блоков в данном случае работает. Возможно кто-то объяснит.

То есть теперь класс должен выглядеть так:

```
.rMenu {
    margin: 0 15px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    width: calc(75% - 60px);
    background-color: gray;
}
```